# Proving formulae from Theory - problem

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic, axioms

I want to prove this formulae $(f(a,f(y,x)) = f(a,f(x,y)))$ from theory T ($a$ and $b$ are functions without arguments):

$$T:$$

$$\alpha: f(f(x,y),z) = f(x,f(y,z))$$

$$\beta: f(x,y) = f(y,x)$$
$$\gamma: P(f(f(a,a),b))$$

So I'm trying to proove that $T |- f(a,f(y,x)) = f(a,f(x,y))$ using rules.

The problem is that my solution is too simple - it is probably incorrect.

So what I need is $\beta$ formulae and reflexivity rule  ( $x=x$ )

1. Since $\beta$ says: $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$, from $f(a,f(x,y))$ I can conclude $f(a,(f(y,x))$
2. So now I have $f(a,f(y,x)) = f(a,f(y,x))$
3. The formula from 2. is in fact reflexivity axiom so it's proven.

Is this proof correct? I don't think so but I can't figure out where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's got the right idea, but it's backwards: you've gone from the thing you're trying to prove, to a true statement, and you need to go the other way.

Start with $f(a, f(x, y))=f(a, f(x, y))$ - true by reflexivity - and apply $\beta$ to get $f(a, f(x, y))=f(a, f(y, x))$.

Comment: I forgot to say that I want to proove this without using completeness theorem. I'm afraid I accidentaly used it in my proof, is it true?

Comment: @Piotr I don't see where you used the completeness theorem, unless you mean that you did so implicitly by not writing your proof completely within some fixed proof system. If that's what you mean, then I can't help further without knowing exactly what proof system you're using (there are many). More to the point, do you understand my comment about going backwards?

Comment: Ok, I have hint that it shouldn't be so simple. Yes I understand, I can start with the   f(a,f(x,y))=f(a,f(x,y)) according to reflexivity axiom and then use Beta to conclude the formulae. Thanks